# How can i create "recursively" folder and sub folder in C#

Tags: c#, directory

**1875  Kovezes
1875    Koszenbanya
1875    Lelenc
1875    Laktanyak
1875    Dologhaz
..
...

1876    Honvedseg
1876    Hidak
**

I have this filestructure in txt-file

"Description: First part of the line is 4 digits-and it can be equal (and root foldername) and It's have to contain only the same 4 digits subfolder. the txt-file is very long approximately 18000 lines

Example:

C:/DATA/1875/Kovezes
C:/DATA/1875/Koszenbanya

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        string line;
        string linecopy;
        int linecopyc;
        //string root = @"C:\Temp";
       // string subdir = @"~/ASD/";
        var file = new System.IO.StreamReader("adatforras.txt");

        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(line);
            //linecopy = line;
            linecopy = line.Substring(0,4);
            label4.Text = linecopy;
            linecopyc = line.Length - 4;
            label4.Text = line.Substring(4, linecopyc);
            if (!Directory.Exists(linecopy))
            { 

              di = Directory.CreateDirectory(linecopy);



      DirectoryInfo dis = di.CreateSubdirectory(label4.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                DirectoryInfo dis = di.CreateSubdirectory(label4.Text);

            }



            }





    }
```

Question is: what is the main problem with this code?

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your substring begins with a space:

```
label4.Text = line.Substring(4, linecopyc);
```

Try trimming it or start at position 5

```
label4.Text = line.Substring(5, linecopyc);
```

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length'

Comment: label4.Text = line.Substring(5, linecopyc-1);

Thank You!

I reorganized the txt file with delimiter ;

Comment: Yes. Sorry - linecopyc needed to be adjusted as well.

Answer (score 0):

C# supports being able to create all directories in the path on the way to the path you want, so you can do something like this:

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
    // Other parts with labels etc.

    var directoryParts = line.split(" "); // To get number and name separately
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("C:\\Data", directoryParts[0], directoryParts[1]));
}
```